# C++ operator "?:"

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Point 
{
    int x;
    int y;  

    Point(int t_x, int t_y)
    {
        x = t_x;
        y = t_y;
    }
};

int main() {
    Point lp(1, 4);
    Point rp(5, 0);

    int min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y;
    lp.x > rp.x ? max_x = lp.x, min_x = rp.x : max_x = rp.x, min_x = lp.x;
    lp.y > rp.y ? max_y = lp.y, min_y = rp.y : max_y = rp.y, min_y = lp.y;
    std::printf("min_x: %d max_x: %d\n", min_x, max_x);
    std::printf("min_y: %d max_y: %d\n", min_y, max_y);
}
```

I think:

```
min_x=1 max_x=5
min_y=0 max_y=4
```

But Real:

```
min_x=1 max_x=5
min_y=4 max_y=4
```

Why?

Comment: Look at the precedence of the operators.

Comment: Oh god, please Please PLEASE don't actually do this.

Comment: Precedence of operations can be tricky when using `?:`, make sure you use `()` around to be safe.

Comment: @Havenard I think it is more to do with the precedence of `,` WRT assignment. I am sure there's a duplicate. I'm looking for it.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I think if that were the issue you'd see the same problem with `x` but we don't.

Comment: @BillyONeal Yeah, I take my previous statement back. Maybe :-)

Comment: Maybe its just the compiler protesting this damn ugly syntax.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find this piece of art?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The comma operator has the lowest [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), and is left-to-right associative. The next lowest precedence operator in your expression is the `?:` ternary operator, which is right-to-left associative. Hence your expression evaluates to:

```
( (lp.y > rp.y) ? ( (max_y = lp.y), (min_y = rp.y) ): (max_y = rp.y) ), (min_y = lp.y);
                                                 // The ?: ends here ^
```

So, `lp.y > rp.y`? YES. Set `max_y = lp.y = 4`. Then evaluate the last `(min_y = lp.y)` (comma operator), so `min_y = lp.y = 4` also.

I really really hope this is an exercise and not actual code though!

Answer (score 2):

Due to operator precedence, the lines

```
lp.x > rp.x ? max_x = lp.x, min_x = rp.x : max_x = rp.x, min_x = lp.x;
lp.y > rp.y ? max_y = lp.y, min_y = rp.y : max_y = rp.y, min_y = lp.y;
```

are equivalent to:

```
(lp.x > rp.x ? (max_x = lp.x, min_x = rp.x) : max_x = rp.x), min_x = lp.x;
(lp.y > rp.y ? (max_y = lp.y, min_y = rp.y) : max_y = rp.y), min_y = lp.y;
```

`min_x` is set to `lp.x` no matter what the values are.
`min_y` is set to `lp.y` no matter what the values are.

You can make your code easy to follow and maintain by using:

```
int min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y;
if ( lp.x > rp.x )
{
   max_x = lp.x;
   min_x = rp.x;
}
else
{
   max_x = rp.x;
   min_x = lp.x;
}
```